# how to listen for POST request with Twilio

Tags: twilio, http-post

I have a monitoring system that is able to send POST request if an event trigger an alarm,

I would like to send that POST request to Twilio so that Twilio can send an SMS to multiple phone numbers.

I am not sure where to start and I am not even sure if twilio can listen for http POST request,
I think that I should use TwiML Bins but I am not sure where to start.

Does anybody have any pointer for me ?

Thank you

Comment: What programming language / service are you using?

Comment: I am trying to create a function in twilio that would listen for a POST request.   
language could be python, javascript.

I know the question is not formulated properly, I am still trying to figure what I need to make this work